# How to initalize nested class members in outer class constructor in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style, c++14, misra

I have a program in C++ that has a nested class as shown below

```
class Outer{
Outer(int val);
private:
    class Inner;
    std::unique_ptr<Inner> obj;

};
Outer::Outer(int val):obj(Inner::CreateInstance(val)) 
{

}
```

My Inner class is in another file and has a private string variable mystring as shown

```
class Inner{
public:
    Inner(int val):mVal(val), mystring(""){
    }
    static std::unique_ptr<Inner> CreateInstance(int val){
    // returns Inner unique ptr
    }
private:
    int mVal
    string mystring;
};
```

Here mVal and mystring is already initialized in Inner class constructor. But I get this MISRA error that says mystring is not initialized in Outer constructor.

> How do I initialize mystring from Outer constructor?
> Even though Inner class initialized the mystring then why do I get this kind of error.

Comment: Are you really allowed to use smart pointers/dynamic allocation in MISRA-C++? I very much doubt that. I also doubt that you are allowed to use anything but C++03.

Comment: Yes we do. The MISRA error is on top of C++11/14 which my code is based upon.

Comment: From an [official source](https://www.misra.org.uk/Activities/MISRAC/tabid/171/Default.aspx): _"The document, known as MISRA C++ Guidelines for the use of the C++ language in critical systems, was published and officially launched on 5 June 2008."_ No later version is mentioned there. So when the MISRA C++ guidelines were published, they could not possibly include C++11 and later. Consequently, using C++11/14 anyway may break the trust we can have in the MISRA usage (since the guidelines was written for previous C++ versions only).

Comment: The tool used to generate the above said error also include the Autosar guideline along with the MISRA. My bad.

Comment: However, How do I initialize mystring from Outer constructor?

Comment: Rule 1 or so of the MISRA document will tell you that you are only allowed to use C++03. Using C++14 for mission-critical software is far beyond questionable practice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this. You dont need to have a forward declaration in the Outer class.
Just flip these classes, I assume.

```
class Inner{
public:
    Inner(int val):mVal(val), mystring(""){
    }
    static std::unique_ptr<Inner> CreateInstance(int val){
        // returns Inner unique ptr
        /* I am using an arbitrary integer as an example */
        return std::make_unique<Inner>(10);
    }
private:
    int mVal;
    std::string mystring;
};



class Outer{
Outer(int val);
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Inner> obj;

};
Outer::Outer(int val):obj(Inner::CreateInstance(val))
{

}
```